# How to create a exe launcher using python in windows

Tags: python, windows, launcher

i need to launch a exe using a python script but also I need to kill it using the same script

A start idea is:

```
process = magicCommand( 'theExe.exe' ) #invoke exe

kill = 'no'
while kill == 'no':
    kill = raw_input()

otherMagicCommand( process ) #kill
```

EDIT

this works in windows for me

```
process = subprocess.Popen( 'theExe.exe' ) #invoke exe

kill = 'no'
while kill == 'no':
    kill = raw_input()

process.kill() #kill
```

Comment: Is what you have not working?

Comment: I'm experimenting with Popen and subprocess.call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) and some good [examples](http://jimmyg.org/blog/2009/working-with-python-subprocess.html) and explanation